# I want put the text on the left and the equation on the middle

Tags: align

[image]

```
\begin{align}
        \Delta U=Q+W\nonumber\\
        \text{Le transformation est adiabatique alors} :\nonumber\\
        W_{compresseur}\:=m\:C_{v}\:\Delta T
    \end{align}
```

I want put the text in the left and all the equation are aligned by the '=' symbol, please

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't use any `&`, so there's no alignment. Could you please make your example compilable (make it a MWE)?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should code  `W_{\text{compress}}` for a correct letterspacing of the word ‘compresseur’.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `\intertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\Delta U&=Q+W\nonumber
\intertext{Le transformation est adiabatique alors :}
W_{compresseur}&=m\:C_{v}\:\Delta T
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Note, it's not necessary to use `\\` or `\nonumber` after intertext. You don't need `\\` before it as well.